# Specify empty columns in facet plot

Tags: r, ggplot2, visualization, facet

I am using gene expression data from trained and control animals. This is relevant because numerous factors can be used to describe each data point.

I have a list of items (gene pathways) that i would like to represent their expression in each condition in a dotplot. Conditions can be described by the factors: training (trained or controlled), direction (up or down) and cell marker population (marker1, marker2, marker3). The dot plot will show the size of the expression as the size of the dot, and the significance of the statistics as the color of the dot.

I am trying to build a nested dot plot of some sort where the first level of the nest is the training factor, the next level is the direction factor, and then with in this level, a total of 4 plots containing 3 columns each (one column for each cell marker population).

The issue is that not every cell marker population has significant data for all of the list of gene pathways on the y axis in each condition.

This seems like a clear job for `ggh4x::facet_nested()`, but this package has no way to select specific scales for each facet plot. when I set `scales = "free"`, all empty columns are removed from each facet plot, including both: columns that don't have any data for those sets of factors AND columns that SHOULD be present, but don't have data so they are excluded.

I am looking for a way to specify which columns i wish to include in each facet to respect the visual symmetry of the plot

```
ggplot(data = EA_Big_Table_filt %>% filter(FDR < 0.01), 
       aes(x = region, y = GOs_ordered, color = -log10(FDR), size = enrichmentRatio)) + 
  geom_point() +
  scale_color_viridis()+
  theme_bw() + 
  ylab("") + 
  xlab("") + 
  scale_y_discrete(limits = rev)+
  ggtitle("GO enrichment analysis")+
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 45,  hjust = 1))+
  facet_nested(. ~ train + reg, scales = "free", space = "free")
```

I have attached 2 images of my data, one where the `ggh4x::facet_nested(scales = "fixed")`(default) and one where `ggh4x::facet_nested(scales = "free")`(closer to what i want to see, but not exactly)

[image: ggh4x::facet_nested(scales = "fixed")]
[image: ggh4x::facet_nested(scales = "free")]

data, code and session info:

data:

```
min_repro_filt <- structure(list(description = c("regulation of trans-synaptic signaling", 
"vesicle-mediated transport in synapse", "axon development", 
"regulation of trans-synaptic signaling", "glutamate receptor signaling pathway", 
"axon development", "gliogenesis", "vesicle-mediated transport in synapse", 
"gliogenesis", "glutamate receptor signaling pathway", "regulation of trans-synaptic signaling", 
"vesicle-mediated transport in synapse", "axon development", 
"glutamate receptor signaling pathway", "regulation of trans-synaptic signaling", 
"gliogenesis", "axon development", "gliogenesis", "vesicle-mediated transport in synapse", 
"regulation of trans-synaptic signaling", "axon development", 
"vesicle-mediated transport in synapse", "glutamate receptor signaling pathway", 
"gliogenesis", "regulation of trans-synaptic signaling", "regulation of trans-synaptic signaling", 
"vesicle-mediated transport in synapse", "glutamate receptor signaling pathway", 
"axon development", "gliogenesis", "cell junction organization", 
"gliogenesis", "regulation of trans-synaptic signaling", "glutamate receptor signaling pathway", 
"axon development", "cell junction organization", "vesicle-mediated transport in synapse", 
"regulation of trans-synaptic signaling", "glutamate receptor signaling pathway", 
"vesicle-mediated transport in synapse", "axon development", 
"gliogenesis", "cell junction organization", "axon development", 
"gliogenesis", "regulation of trans-synaptic signaling", "glutamate receptor signaling pathway", 
"vesicle-mediated transport in synapse", "cell junction organization", 
"cell junction organization", "gliogenesis", "regulation of trans-synaptic signaling", 
"axon development", "axon development", "glutamate receptor signaling pathway", 
"vesicle-mediated transport in synapse", "regulation of trans-synaptic signaling", 
"gliogenesis", "vesicle-mediated transport in synapse", "glutamate receptor signaling pathway"
), enrichmentRatio = c(6.68500452254813, 8.65118232329758, 4.89859154929577, 
6.2819380733945, 9.26760563380282, 3.62291666666667, 2.49382842509603, 
4.18795871559633, 3.31990909090909, 4.1125, 6.46920452002685, 
7.49065786529425, 4.94837398373984, 6.01829268292683, 3.05371989678899, 
2.69911308203991, 2.7171875, 2.76659090909091, 2.61747419724771, 
5.26023800026592, 5.04057971014493, 4.85560430793777, 4.76811594202899, 
2.56611330698287, 3.28467350242849, 5.19782110091743, 5.34633027522936, 
8.75, 3.08333333333333, 2.20445490764216, 2.3685073658853, 1.88363636363636, 
1.5572754852151, 1.96613545816733, 1.27018592297477, 1.2046511627907, 
1.22357359552615, 3.74002543656578, 7.68691588785047, 3.82700277229987, 
2.70872274143302, 2.28959247648903, 2.0337142475274, 1.540780651341, 
1.51688473520249, 1.24355095961194, 1.65445402298851, 1.28366550669619, 
0.881909729768891, 2.97470777501731, 2.55824868651489, 2.88824739006643, 
2.87334770114943, 1.87807939287799, 4.25431034482759, 2.6475601075609, 
1.46688571474477, 1.71719435736677, 1.2713009527788, 1.44045534150613
), FDR = c(2.73232271030821e-07, 1.91352946274925e-05, 0.000799115680928431, 
0.00737891722498407, 0.0251647909352357, 0.377609720014827, 0.482007003299911, 
0.559306907495358, 0.622940182995214, 0.824998329823089, 4.55977451352396e-08, 
8.80653616306404e-05, 0.000190625247077728, 0.171932712695981, 
0.286373116680475, 0.33443668772753, 0.408598183442779, 0.610959581662353, 
0.769244655353647, 0.000673089562158502, 0.00146411622888287, 
0.066152305546214, 0.500038510445596, 0.514416053344859, 0.648796603956836, 
4.50750547997814e-13, 2.86037431496133e-06, 3.76246830418777e-05, 
0.000518693843230148, 0.0446535816600178, 0.0446535816600178, 
0.307323155761676, 0.430536006591497, 0.551164801987552, 0.733800798695753, 
0.808819620683588, 0.863106002361249, 4.34523528269892e-11, 2.7178716477394e-07, 
1.6300065634689e-05, 8.05719824708007e-05, 0.00157307543882146, 
0.0408955420096159, 0.117659135740778, 0.372628642468256, 0.526802985860736, 
0.538620753649825, 0.599873558319722, 0.936848868711327, 6.37736750075391e-05, 
0.00018792064357287, 0.00216261020136876, 0.00216261020136876, 
0.0192479493927484, 0.12526745194893, 0.12526745194893, 0.228192711206325, 
0.530843810076351, 0.60232342998248, 0.639795828874161), region = c("TRArcPos_TRArcNeg", 
"TRArcPos_TRArcNeg", "TRArcPos_TRArcNeg", "TRArcPos_TRArcNeg", 
"TRArcPos_TRArcNeg", "TRArcPos_TRArcNeg", "TRArcPos_TRArcNeg", 
"TRArcPos_TRArcNeg", "TRArcPos_TRArcNeg", "TRArcPos_TRArcNeg", 
"TREgr1Pos_TREgr1Neg", "TREgr1Pos_TREgr1Neg", "TREgr1Pos_TREgr1Neg", 
"TREgr1Pos_TREgr1Neg", "TREgr1Pos_TREgr1Neg", "TREgr1Pos_TREgr1Neg", 
"TREgr1Pos_TREgr1Neg", "TREgr1Pos_TREgr1Neg", "TREgr1Pos_TREgr1Neg", 
"TRJunPos_TRJunNeg", "TRJunPos_TRJunNeg", "TRJunPos_TRJunNeg", 
"TRJunPos_TRJunNeg", "TRJunPos_TRJunNeg", "TRJunPos_TRJunNeg", 
"UTArcPos_UTArcNeg", "UTArcPos_UTArcNeg", "UTArcPos_UTArcNeg", 
"UTArcPos_UTArcNeg", "UTArcPos_UTArcNeg", "UTArcPos_UTArcNeg", 
"UTArcPos_UTArcNeg", "UTArcPos_UTArcNeg", "UTArcPos_UTArcNeg", 
"UTArcPos_UTArcNeg", "UTArcPos_UTArcNeg", "UTArcPos_UTArcNeg", 
"UTEgr1Pos_UTEgr1Neg", "UTEgr1Pos_UTEgr1Neg", "UTEgr1Pos_UTEgr1Neg", 
"UTEgr1Pos_UTEgr1Neg", "UTEgr1Pos_UTEgr1Neg", "UTEgr1Pos_UTEgr1Neg", 
"UTEgr1Pos_UTEgr1Neg", "UTEgr1Pos_UTEgr1Neg", "UTEgr1Pos_UTEgr1Neg", 
"UTEgr1Pos_UTEgr1Neg", "UTEgr1Pos_UTEgr1Neg", "UTEgr1Pos_UTEgr1Neg", 
"UTJunPos_UTJunNeg", "UTJunPos_UTJunNeg", "UTJunPos_UTJunNeg", 
"UTJunPos_UTJunNeg", "UTJunPos_UTJunNeg", "UTJunPos_UTJunNeg", 
"UTJunPos_UTJunNeg", "UTJunPos_UTJunNeg", "UTJunPos_UTJunNeg", 
"UTJunPos_UTJunNeg", "UTJunPos_UTJunNeg"), reg = c("UP", "UP", 
"UP", "DOWN", "UP", "DOWN", "UP", "DOWN", "DOWN", "DOWN", "UP", 
"UP", "UP", "UP", "DOWN", "UP", "DOWN", "DOWN", "DOWN", "UP", 
"UP", "UP", "UP", "UP", "DOWN", "UP", "UP", "UP", "UP", "DOWN", 
"DOWN", "UP", "DOWN", "DOWN", "DOWN", "UP", "DOWN", "UP", "UP", 
"UP", "UP", "DOWN", "DOWN", "DOWN", "UP", "DOWN", "DOWN", "DOWN", 
"UP", "DOWN", "DOWN", "UP", "UP", "DOWN", "UP", "UP", "DOWN", 
"UP", "DOWN", "DOWN"), ieg = c("Arc", "Arc", "Arc", "Arc", "Arc", 
"Arc", "Arc", "Arc", "Arc", "Arc", "Egr1", "Egr1", "Egr1", "Egr1", 
"Egr1", "Egr1", "Egr1", "Egr1", "Egr1", "Jun", "Jun", "Jun", 
"Jun", "Jun", "Jun", "Arc", "Arc", "Arc", "Arc", "Arc", "Arc", 
"Arc", "Arc", "Arc", "Arc", "Arc", "Arc", "Egr1", "Egr1", "Egr1", 
"Egr1", "Egr1", "Egr1", "Egr1", "Egr1", "Egr1", "Egr1", "Egr1", 
"Egr1", "Jun", "Jun", "Jun", "Jun", "Jun", "Jun", "Jun", "Jun", 
"Jun", "Jun", "Jun"), train = c("TR", "TR", "TR", "TR", "TR", 
"TR", "TR", "TR", "TR", "TR", "TR", "TR", "TR", "TR", "TR", "TR", 
"TR", "TR", "TR", "TR", "TR", "TR", "TR", "TR", "TR", "UT", "UT", 
"UT", "UT", "UT", "UT", "UT", "UT", "UT", "UT", "UT", "UT", "UT", 
"UT", "UT", "UT", "UT", "UT", "UT", "UT", "UT", "UT", "UT", "UT", 
"UT", "UT", "UT", "UT", "UT", "UT", "UT", "UT", "UT", "UT", "UT"
)), class = c("grouped_df", "tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, 
-60L), groups = structure(list(region = c("TRArcPos_TRArcNeg", 
"TREgr1Pos_TREgr1Neg", "TRJunPos_TRJunNeg", "UTArcPos_UTArcNeg", 
"UTEgr1Pos_UTEgr1Neg", "UTJunPos_UTJunNeg"), .rows = structure(list(
    1:10, 11:19, 20:25, 26:37, 38:49, 50:60), ptype = integer(0), class = c("vctrs_list_of", 
"vctrs_vctr", "list"))), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
), row.names = c(NA, -6L), .drop = TRUE))
```

ggplot code:

library(tidyverse)
library(ggplot2)
library(viridisLite)
library(viridis)
library(gghx4)

```
ggplot(data = min_repro_filt %>% filter(FDR < 0.01), 
       aes(x = region, y = description, color = -log10(FDR), size = enrichmentRatio)) + 
  geom_point() +
  scale_color_viridis()+
  theme_bw() + 
  ylab("") + 
  xlab("") + 
  scale_y_discrete(limits = rev)+
  ggtitle("GO enrichment analysis")+
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 45,  hjust = 1))+
  facet_nested(. ~ train + reg, scales = "free", space = "free") +
  scale_x_discrete(labels=c("UTArcPos_UTArcNeg" = expression("Untrained"^italic("Arc+")*"vs. Untrained"^italic("Arc-")),
                            "TRArcPos_TRArcNeg" = expression("Trained"^italic("Arc+")*"vs. Trained"^italic("Arc-")),
                            "UTEgr1Pos_UTEgr1Neg" = expression("Untrained"^italic("Egr1+")*"vs. Untrained"^italic("Egr1-")),
                            "TREgr1Pos_TREgr1Neg" = expression("Trained"^italic("Egr1+")*"vs. Trained"^italic("Egr1-")),
                            "UTJunPos_UTJunNeg" = expression("Untrained"^italic("Jun+")*"vs. Untrained"^italic("Jun-")),
                            "TRJunPos_TRJunNeg" = expression("Trained"^italic("Jun+")*"vs. Trained"^italic("Jun-"))))
```

session info

```
R version 4.1.1 (2021-08-10)
Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin17.0 (64-bit)
Running under: macOS Monterey 12.6.3

Matrix products: default
LAPACK: /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.1/Resources/lib/libRlapack.dylib

locale:
[1] en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/C/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8

attached base packages:
[1] grid      stats4    stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods  
[9] base     

other attached packages:
 [1] ggh4x_0.2.6            ggthemes_4.2.4         SeuratObject_4.1.3    
 [4] Seurat_4.3.0           hrbrthemes_0.8.0       dendsort_0.3.4        
 [7] ComplexHeatmap_2.11.1  broom_1.0.5            ggpubr_0.6.0          
[10] SuperExactTest_1.1.0   org.Mm.eg.db_3.13.0    AnnotationDbi_1.54.1  
[13] IRanges_2.28.0         S4Vectors_0.32.3       Biobase_2.52.0        
[16] BiocGenerics_0.40.0    BiocManager_1.30.22    clusterProfiler_4.0.5 
[19] viridis_0.6.4          viridisLite_0.4.2      WebGestaltR_0.4.5     
[22] patchwork_1.1.3        ggbreak_0.1.2          EnhancedVolcano_1.10.0
[25] ggrepel_0.9.3          lubridate_1.9.2        forcats_1.0.0         
[28] stringr_1.5.0          dplyr_1.1.2            purrr_1.0.1           
[31] readr_2.1.4            tidyr_1.3.0            tibble_3.2.1          
[34] tidyverse_2.0.0        ggplot2_3.4.3          GeneOverlap_1.28.0    

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
  [1] scattermore_0.8         knitr_1.44              bit64_4.0.5            
  [4] irlba_2.3.5.1           data.table_1.14.8       KEGGREST_1.32.0        
  [7] RCurl_1.98-1.12         doParallel_1.0.17       generics_0.1.3         
 [10] callr_3.7.3             cowplot_1.1.1           usethis_2.2.2          
 [13] RSQLite_2.3.1           shadowtext_0.1.2        RANN_2.6.1             
 [16] future_1.33.0           bit_4.0.5               tzdb_0.3.0             
 [19] enrichplot_1.12.3       spatstat.data_3.0-1     httpuv_1.6.10          
 [22] xfun_0.39               hms_1.1.3               evaluate_0.22          
 [25] promises_1.2.0.1        fansi_1.0.4             caTools_1.18.2         
 [28] igraph_1.4.2            DBI_1.1.3               htmlwidgets_1.6.2      
 [31] apcluster_1.4.10        spatstat.geom_3.2-1     ellipsis_0.3.2         
 [34] fontLiberation_0.1.0    backports_1.4.1         fontBitstreamVera_0.1.1
 [37] deldir_1.0-6            vctrs_0.6.2             remotes_2.4.2.1        
 [40] ROCR_1.0-11             abind_1.4-5             cachem_1.0.8           
 [43] withr_2.5.1             ggforce_0.4.1           RVenn_1.1.0            
 [46] progressr_0.14.0        vroom_1.6.3             sctransform_0.3.5      
 [49] treeio_1.16.2           prettyunits_1.2.0       goftest_1.2-3          
 [52] svglite_2.1.1           cluster_2.1.4           DOSE_3.18.3            
 [55] ape_5.7-1               lazyeval_0.2.2          crayon_1.5.2           
 [58] crul_1.4.0              spatstat.explore_3.1-0  pkgconfig_2.0.3        
 [61] labeling_0.4.3          tweenr_2.0.2            GenomeInfoDb_1.28.4    
 [64] pkgload_1.3.3           nlme_3.1-162            vipor_0.4.5            
 [67] devtools_2.4.5          rlang_1.1.1             globals_0.16.2         
 [70] lifecycle_1.0.3         miniUI_0.1.1.1          downloader_0.4         
 [73] fontquiver_0.2.1        httpcode_0.3.0          extrafontdb_1.0        
 [76] ggrastr_1.0.2           polyclip_1.10-4         matrixStats_0.63.0     
 [79] lmtest_0.9-40           rngtools_1.5.2          Matrix_1.5-1           
 [82] aplot_0.2.1             carData_3.0-5           zoo_1.8-12             
 [85] beeswarm_0.4.0          processx_3.8.1          GlobalOptions_0.1.2    
 [88] whisker_0.4.1           ggridges_0.5.4          rjson_0.2.21           
 [91] png_0.1-8               bitops_1.0-7            KernSmooth_2.23-21     
 [94] Biostrings_2.60.2       blob_1.2.4              shape_1.4.6            
 [97] doRNG_1.8.6             qvalue_2.24.0           parallelly_1.36.0      
[100] spatstat.random_3.1-4   rstatix_0.7.2           gridGraphics_0.5-1     
[103] ggsignif_0.6.4          scales_1.2.1            memoise_2.0.1          
[106] magrittr_2.0.3          plyr_1.8.8              ica_1.0-3              
[109] gplots_3.1.3            zlibbioc_1.38.0         compiler_4.1.1         
[112] scatterpie_0.2.1        RColorBrewer_1.1-3      ash_1.0-15             
[115] clue_0.3-64             fitdistrplus_1.1-11     cli_3.6.1              
[118] urlchecker_1.0.1        XVector_0.32.0          listenv_0.9.0          
[121] ps_1.7.5                pbapply_1.7-2           mgcv_1.8-42            
[124] MASS_7.3-60             tidyselect_1.2.0        stringi_1.7.12         
[127] proj4_1.0-12            GOSemSim_2.18.1         fastmatch_1.1-3        
[130] tools_4.1.1             timechange_0.2.0        future.apply_1.11.0    
[133] parallel_4.1.1          circlize_0.4.15         rstudioapi_0.15.0      
[136] foreach_1.5.2           gridExtra_2.3           farver_2.1.1           
[139] Rtsne_0.16              ggraph_2.1.0            digest_0.6.31          
[142] shiny_1.7.5             gfonts_0.2.0            Rcpp_1.0.10            
[145] car_3.1-2               ggalt_0.4.0             later_1.3.1            
[148] RcppAnnoy_0.0.20        gdtools_0.3.3           httr_1.4.7             
[151] colorspace_2.1-0        fs_1.6.2                tensor_1.5             
[154] reticulate_1.28         splines_4.1.1           uwot_0.1.14            
[157] yulab.utils_0.1.0       ggVennDiagram_1.2.3     tidytree_0.4.5         
[160] spatstat.utils_3.0-3    graphlayouts_1.0.0      sp_1.6-0               
[163] ggplotify_0.1.2         sessioninfo_1.2.2       plotly_4.10.2          
[166] systemfonts_1.0.4       xtable_1.8-4            jsonlite_1.8.4         
[169] ggtree_3.0.4            tidygraph_1.2.3         ggfun_0.1.3            
[172] R6_2.5.1                profvis_0.3.8           pillar_1.9.0           
[175] htmltools_0.5.5         mime_0.12               glue_1.6.2             
[178] fastmap_1.1.1           BiocParallel_1.26.2     codetools_0.2-19       
[181] maps_3.4.1              fgsea_1.18.0            pkgbuild_1.4.2         
[184] utf8_1.2.3              lattice_0.21-8          spatstat.sparse_3.0-1  
[187] curl_5.0.0              ggbeeswarm_0.7.2        leiden_0.4.3           
[190] gtools_3.9.4            GO.db_3.13.0            Rttf2pt1_1.3.12        
[193] limma_3.48.3            survival_3.5-5          rmarkdown_2.25         
[196] munsell_0.5.0           GetoptLong_1.0.5        DO.db_2.9              
[199] GenomeInfoDbData_1.2.6  iterators_1.0.14        reshape2_1.4.4         
[202] gtable_0.3.4            extrafont_0.19
```

output:
[image]

I'm trying to get those three columns on all 4 facets

Comment: That's the default behavior of `scales="free"` But actually the `ggh4x` package is famous for offering an option to set the scales individually per panel: See https://teunbrand.github.io/ggh4x/articles/Facets.html#position-scales. For more help please provide [a minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) including a snippet of your data or some fake data best shared via `dput()`.

Comment: @stefan I have added my best attempt at minimally reproducible code and data (that was my first time ever doing that on stack overflow), I hope this help you (or someone else) help me better.

Answer (score 0):

I found an answer using `gghx4` as user stefan suggested. specifically, I used `+ gghx4::facetted_pos_scales(x = scales)` as an addition to my `ggplot2` expression

It felt like a lengthy brute force (but mostly because the length of my variable titles are so long), seen below:

```
scales <- list(
  scale_x_discrete(
    limits = c("TRArcPos_TRArcNeg", "TREgr1Pos_TREgr1Neg", "TRJunPos_TRJunNeg"),
    labels=c("TRArcPos_TRArcNeg" = expression("Trained"^italic("Arc+")*"vs. Trained"^italic("Arc-")),
                                 "TREgr1Pos_TREgr1Neg" = expression("Trained"^italic("Egr1+")*"vs. Trained"^italic("Egr1-")),
                                 "TRJunPos_TRJunNeg" = expression("Trained"^italic("Jun+")*"vs. Trained"^italic("Jun-")))),
  scale_x_discrete(
    limits = c("TRArcPos_TRArcNeg", "TREgr1Pos_TREgr1Neg", "TRJunPos_TRJunNeg"),
    labels=c("TRArcPos_TRArcNeg" = expression("Trained"^italic("Arc+")*"vs. Trained"^italic("Arc-")),
                            "TREgr1Pos_TREgr1Neg" = expression("Trained"^italic("Egr1+")*"vs. Trained"^italic("Egr1-")),
                            "TRJunPos_TRJunNeg" = expression("Trained"^italic("Jun+")*"vs. Trained"^italic("Jun-")))),
  scale_x_discrete(
    limits = c("UTArcPos_UTArcNeg","UTEgr1Pos_UTEgr1Neg","UTJunPos_UTJunNeg"),
    labels=c("UTArcPos_UTArcNeg" = expression("Untrained"^italic("Arc+")*"vs. Untrained"^italic("Arc-")),
                            "UTEgr1Pos_UTEgr1Neg" = expression("Untrained"^italic("Egr1+")*"vs. Untrained"^italic("Egr1-")),
                            "UTJunPos_UTJunNeg" = expression("Untrained"^italic("Jun+")*"vs. Untrained"^italic("Jun-")))),
  scale_x_discrete(
    limits = c("UTArcPos_UTArcNeg","UTEgr1Pos_UTEgr1Neg","UTJunPos_UTJunNeg"),
    labels=c("UTArcPos_UTArcNeg" = expression("Untrained"^italic("Arc+")*"vs. Untrained"^italic("Arc-")),
                            "UTEgr1Pos_UTEgr1Neg" = expression("Untrained"^italic("Egr1+")*"vs. Untrained"^italic("Egr1-")),
                            "UTJunPos_UTJunNeg" = expression("Untrained"^italic("Jun+")*"vs. Untrained"^italic("Jun-"))))
)
```

4 separate discrete axis expressions for the 4 facets, in the order they appear in the graph.

And the result looks as intended:
[image: it worked!]